# Parse local variable stored in file into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

I have a Flask website running. I would like to have a iOS kinda switch to turn my amplifier on and off. I have created the switch as a `<div>` and I am able to switch the `<div>` to on with jQuery `toggleClass`.

Everytime I toggle the switch a shell script runs and turn either on or off the amplifier. Also it stores a "1" (for ON) or "0" (for OFF) in a local file by running a shell script through appRoute in Flask. I hoped it would be easy to implement some javascript reading the state from the local file to toggle the switch - when visiting the website. However I am clueless how to make this `if` state - getting the parameter from the local file and update it each time I visit the website.

Anyone with good ideas for a solution to this?

Comment: Use AJAX to query the server.

Comment: Consider using local storage assuming the setting is supposed to be unique for each unique user. No file operations required.

Comment: The Web Server will be the API. The browser is then a Client. You can make requests, via AJAX or HTTP, and get the current status from the API, via GET or you can set the status with POST or GET if you like. The JavaScript will be basic, and it will require some server side scripting to be the API, this can be Python or whatever you have that is part of the Web Server.

Answer (score 1):

So I suspect you have something like this:

```
+-----+        +-------------+        +---------+
| AMP |--------| RPI         |        | iOS     | 
+-----+        | 192.168.1.2 |  ) ) ) | Browser |
               +-------------+        +---------+
```

I suggest that on your Rasberry Pi, you have a local file, lets say `/var/www/html/amp-status.json`. Your path might be different depending on your Web Server, but it should be somewhere in your web server path. You may also have a Python script populates this file with the status of the Amp. I suggest the following:

```
{ "status": 1 }
```

Or:

```
{ "status": 0 }
```

Now, on your iOS Device, you can navigate to 192.168.1.2/amp-status.json to check the status of the Amp. Also you can use jQuery in a webpage to do this via AJAX.

```
$.getJSON("amp-status.json", function(r){
  $("#amp-status"),val(r.status);
});
```

This is a simple way to read the status from a Web Server. JSON is a very good way to pass data from server to client as it can be easily interpreted by JavaScrip/jQuery. You can use Text, HTML, or XML if you prefer.

**Update - Flask Example**

```
# Get Amp Status via Python, store in 'a'
# Import proper library
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/_get_amp_status')
def get_amp_status():
    return jsonify(status=a)
```

See More:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#module-flask.json

Comment: Hi Twisty, I am using Flask, so I do not have a simple local website to read the file.

Comment: @SchnitteKing never used Flask so I did a bit of research. You can make a Flask page that exports a value in JSON dynamically. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#module-flask.json check the jsonify section.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Thanks for you time. Have a good Christmas.

Comment: Just have your flask server keep the state in memory and dump it to a backup file when it changes and read it on startup rather than with every request.